# Excel Ribbon Dropdown

Tags: xml, excel, vba, ribbon

I have an Excel add-in that adds a tab to my ribbon with XML.

The tab has a dropdown with three options. When I choose an option different to the current value, then the macro runs fine, but when I click on the dropdown and the value stays the same, the macro doesn't run.

The macro updates the format of the selected cells. How can I run a macro when I click on the dropwdown, even if the value stays the same. Here is my xml and vb code:

XML:

```
<group id="pvt" label="Formatting">       
  <dropDown id="ddItem" label="Date Format" onAction="dtFormat">
  <item id="Item1" label="dd-mmm-yyyy"/>
  <item id="Item2" label="dd-mmm-yy"/>
  <item id="Item3" label="dd/mmm/yyyy"/>
  </dropDown>
</group >
```

VB.NET:

```
Public Sub dtFormat(control As IRibbonControl, ID As String, index As Integer)
    If index = 0 Then
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    ElseIf index = 1 Then
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
    ElseIf index = 2 Then
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd\/mmm\/yyyy"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the forward slashes in the third format mask?

Comment: What happens if you add `index = -1` just before exiting dtFormat? (apologies for asking what appears to be a rudimentary question but it takes quite a bit of time to set up a 'test bench' for a custom ribbon so testing is prohibitive).

Comment: The escaping of forward slashes is how excel works when formatting a cell to dd/mmm/yyyy.  `index = -1` does nothing different.

Comment: Really?!? That isn't how my excel ever worked but good to know when attempting debug on someone else's system.

Comment: That's how the dropdown works. Add a button to trigger the numberformat change instead, using the value in the dropdown.